# Why am I getting this error after upgrade?: 'Version of Realm file on disk is higher than current schema version'

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6, realm

I upgraded from Realm 0.89.? to 0.90.5. Nothing changed about my Realm file nor my migration block. However, now I am getting this error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Version of Realm file on disk is higher than current schema version'`

I tried changing the migration block to set the schema version to 999, but that didn't work.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Are you making sure to set the schema version _before_ opening the Realm for the first time?

Comment: Yes, I am setting the schema version in the AppDelegate.swift file before any other reference to realm (except ```import Realm```).

Answer (score 0):

You can check version of Realm file on disk with function [schemaVersionAtPath](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Functions.html#/s:F10RealmSwift19schemaVersionAtPathFTSS13encryptionKeyGSqCSo6NSData_5errorGVSs33AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointerGSqCSo7NSError___GSqVSs6UInt64_), maybe it is greater than 999.

```
public func schemaVersionAtPath(realmPath: String, encryptionKey: NSData? = nil,
                                error: NSErrorPointer = nil) -> UInt64?
```